# Abort running of stored procedure when another instance is running

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which is supposed to execute at a regular interval to do some heavy background processing on the backend. The amount of data the stored procedure has to deal with is variable.

I intend to set up the stored procedure as a scheduled job.

Because the processing must be done sequentially, I need to ensure only one instance of the stored procedure runs at any time.

Given how heavy the data is, it is possible that the scheduled job may activate another instance before the first one has had time to complete.

My question is: how does one check for other instances of the stored procedure and abort if one exists already?

Comment: If the job runs out of SQLAgent it shouldn't create a new instance while the old one is running. If it is running out of Task Scheduler, there is an setting for this on the Settings tab: "If the task is already running... don't start a new instance". If running out of Tivoli there is probably an option too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create semaphore table to set flags and check for them in your procedure.